# New To Cassandra - SliceQuery giving error Not Enough bytes to read value of component 0

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift, hector

I am having trouble trying to query a Column Family (CF) with a composite key of 2 columns: `comment_key` and `prattle_key`.

Here is the CF definition:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_key text,
  prattle_key text,
  parent_key text,
  depth int,
  author text,
  date_created timestamp,
  body text,
  PRIMARY KEY (comment_key, prattle_key)
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
```

Here is my Java Code:

```
Composite key = new Composite();
key.addComponent(prattleKey, StringSerializer.get());
key.addComponent(commentKey, StringSerializer.get());

SliceQuery<Composite, String, String> query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keyspace, CompositeSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());

query.setColumnFamily("comments").setKey(key).setColumnNames("parent_key", "body", "depth", "date", "author");

QueryResult<ColumnSlice<String, String>> queryResult = query.execute();
ColumnSlice<String, String> cs = queryResult.get();
```

I get the following error message:

```
InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)
```

Using the command line CQL utility, I can select all 3 rows in the ColumnFamily just fine, so I know that there is data in there.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a compound primary key, the first key is used as the row (or partition) key and the remaining primary keys are used as part of the column headers for the non-key columns.  For example, in your case, the column name for CQL column body is a compound value made up of the value of the prattle_key value and the string "body".  That also means that a column family row can contain multiple CQL rows that all have the same comment_key value but different prattle_key values.

I think the error you get comes from the fact that you were trying to process a rowkey value that had only the comment_key with a compound type that had two components.  Change your key value so that is just the comment_key and look for column names that come back with the first component equal to the prattle_key value.